# Implementing an html/css framework with a master page in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio, 960.gs

I'm working on a website for a school project and I designed it in photoshop with 9 columns.

To make life easier I want to use the 960 grid system (Custom for 9 columns) in order to build the design in html/css.

Part of the projects requirement is that I need to use a master page and web forms in c# however I'm not sure how to implement the 960 framework within that.

does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: if u paste some code, I will help you

Comment: Why is a master page different from any other html? it's just the wrapping html, just seperate you're markup to the outer part which doesn't change (it can be only the <html>,<head> and <body>) and everything else inside you're aspx pages that uses this master page (which will refence the css and script files at the head).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're being forced to use ASP.Net Web forms. I'd typically recommend you use ASP.Net MVC instead, and it does support Master pages, but really everything is a view, and I expect you would get push-back from the professor. So, to keep with the standard ASP.Net Web forms approach, you should create a new ASP.Net WebSite, and check off that you want a master page. Then Visual Studio will create the Master page for you, and any new aspx pages you create you can click a box to have them inherit from the master page.

If you look at the .Master page, you'll see the same HTML you would see on any site, including the ,  and  tags. You should just include the .css file that contains your 960 framework file, just like you would on any Web page. Then the rest f the page will use the 960 grid, and you can put the necessary col# classes inside the class tag (or CssClass for ASP.Net controls) to get the display to work correctly.